# Drupal behaviors not attached after Ajax load

Tags: ajax

I'm facing a weird problem on my clean Drupal Installation 
I attached a js library to page with this

```
function fs_gal_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'fs_gal/fs_gal';
}
```

This js file I have:

```
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
  'use strict';
   Drupal.behaviors.GalJs = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
        alert("Gal");
    }
  };
}) (jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

In my custom theme I created a Ajax call:

```
$('.button a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "path-to-controller",
        cache: false,
        success: function(htmlText) {
            $('.text-container').html(htmlText);
        }
    });
});
```

After clicking the button, the text is correctly replaced in the `.test-container` but the library is not re-attached to the newly changed DOM.
Do someone know a technique to re-attach all behaviors to the content injected after an Ajax call ?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: @Clive solution's fixed everything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Behaviours are fired after a *Drupal* AJAX call - a call to jQuery.ajax isn’t the same thing.

Fortunately it’s easy to attach them yourself, just add this in the success callback when you’ve finished manipulating the DOM:

```
Drupal.attachBehaviors();
```

Comment: Excellent @Clive you point me to the right direction. 1) I didn't know that Jquery and Drupal AJAX calls aren't the same. `Drupal.ajax({ url: endpoint }).execute();` was a solution too  2) . Attaching back manually all behaviors with `Drupal.attachBehaviors();` works well too. Thank you very much Clive